# How to find time complexities when varying the input size?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I'm wondering how you calculate the time complexities of a function when `doubling` the input sizes. I'm specifically referring to the famous `Algorithms Design` practice problems.

[Example Problem Questions Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcprs.png)

The solutions:
[Solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOjdq.png)

At first, it looked like he just plugged in the values into the function. `n^3` becomes `(2n)^3`, therefore that becomes `8n^3`, so `8 times slower`.

Where I begin getting confused is looking at `nlogn` and `2^n`. Is there a certain trick I am missing to perform this computation or is it just mathematical substitution? I've read through the chapter in his book and can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use simple identities:

```
2nlog(2n) = 2n(logn + log2) = 2nlogn + 2nlog2 

2^(2n) = (2^n)^2
```

Seems obvious which answers fit.